# How do I remove cases with missing data, contingent on having a specific amount of variables missing?

Tags: r

I have a large data set, and some cases are missing a variable here and there, but I have some cases where participants answered no questions at all, or only 1/150 questions. Is there a way to get rid of cases missing >x variables, but keep cases with

```
case k1   k2   k3
1    na   2    3
2    3    1    5
3    1    na   2
4    na   na   na
```

So in this case, I want a formula that would remove case 4 only. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, my matrix didn't pop up right here.
Case 1 - 1 missing data point
Case 2 - no missing
Case 3 - 1 missing data point
Case 4 - all values na

Comment: @PoGibas
I had a bit of trouble at first, but I think I figured it out. So renaming my data frame as "data" and forcing cases with at least 35 variables accounted for, with your solution it would look like this...
<br/>
nMissing <- 35 <br/>
foo <- apply(data, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) <br/>
data[!foo >= nMissing, ] <br/>

And while that showed me the frame I wanted, it didn't write it. So I made one minor edit. <br/>

nMissing <- 35 <br/>
foo <- apply(data, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) <br/>
data <- data[!foo >= nMissing, ] <br/>

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example where your matrix is named `yourMatrix` and you let < than 2 missing values.

```
# Number of missing values to start removing cases
nMissing <- 2
foo <- apply(yourMatrix, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
yourMatrix[!foo >= nMissing, ]
```

Comment: `foo <- rowSums(is.na(DF))` should work; and I think `!x >= y` is too obscure vs `x < y`...

Comment: `df[rowSums(is.na(df))<2, ]`

Comment: @Frank, This actually worked better. The reduced dataset with PoGibas solution returned 3152 cases out of 13730, where this returned 10578 cases. 

What I did at first, which was more complicated, was to recode all na's as 99, and then sum the rows in excel, find the cutoff point (in this case it was somewhere 8850) and kick out all cases with sum > 8850. But I think this way is easier, and comparing to what I did before produced similar results.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked best for me.

```
MyDataset2 <- MYDataset
nMissing <- 23
foo <- rowSums(is.na(MyDataset2))
MyDataset2 <- MyDataset2[!foo < nMissing, ]
```